# Create edgelist of all possible combinations

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing a list of people and corresponding lat lon coordinates of where they work. Essentially I want to create a new data frame that represents an edge list showing distance between each person and all others in the original data frame. I know how to compute distance but am struggling with my for loops.

Original data frame looks like this (coord = tuple):

```
name, coord
Bob -30, 142
Jack 32, 3
Alfred 40, - 116
```

I need to generate new data frame like this:

```
from, to, from_coord, to_coord
Bob, Bob, -30, 142, -30, 142
Bob, Jack, -30, 142, 32, 3
Bob, Alfred, -30, 142, 40, -116
Jack, Jack 32, 3, 32, 3
Jack, Alfred 32, 3, 40, -116
Alfred, Alfred 40, -116, 40, -116
```

Once this is sorted I can easily compute distance.

I tried using using two nested for loops to create this but am stuffing up my cbind, rbinds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base solution using `setNames` and `with` and then using `expand.grid`

```
x <- with(df, setNames(name, coord))
x1 <- cbind(expand.grid(x,x),expand.grid(names(x),names(x)))
colnames(x1)<-c("from","to","from_coord","to_coord")

    from     to from_coord to_coord
1    Bob    Bob   -30, 142 -30, 142
2   Jack    Bob      32, 3 -30, 142
3 Alfred    Bob   40, -116 -30, 142
4    Bob   Jack   -30, 142    32, 3
5   Jack   Jack      32, 3    32, 3
6 Alfred   Jack   40, -116    32, 3
7    Bob Alfred   -30, 142 40, -116
8   Jack Alfred      32, 3 40, -116
9 Alfred Alfred   40, -116 40, -116
```

Comment: This works with tuple example I provided. However, I note the coordinate data is stored as a data frame not as tuples. I will keep trying. Thanks for the quick reponse!

Comment: The structure of my data frame is as follows:

Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame': 18 obs. of 2 variables:
$ name : chr "Erik" "Datha" "Tom" "Valerie" ...
$ coordinate:'data.frame': 18 obs. of 2 variables:
..$ lon: num 147 153 147 147 147 ...
..$ lat: num -42.9 -27.5 -42.9 -42.9 -42.9 ...

Comment: try dput(head(your_data, n = 20))  if it would improve things, though jalapic works and does what you said you wanted as you could figure the distance. setNames applies to vectors (perhaps your 'tuples') as well as df.

Comment: Interesting, when I try head(df) when I have coordinate dataframe I get this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(X[[i]], ...) : undefined columns selected.